# drawing graphics to form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, graphics

i want to call a function from an external script which draws a shape.

the form currently opens up blank with no shape on it and no error.

below is empty form that calls a function from a different file

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    other_fff functions1 = new other_fff();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        functions1.draw_circle(this);
    }
}
```

below is where i get my draw function

```
class other_fff
{
    public void draw_circle(Form1 the_form)
    {
        Pen Pen1 = new Pen(Color.Blue, 9);
        Graphics g = the_form.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawEllipse(Pen1, 50, 50, 10, 5); // does not work 
    }
}
```

how can i make this draw

Comment: you need to disable paint event or use it in every on paint event ... also then you should use graphics passed to this event

Comment: Develop an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) that specifies a method that receives a `Graphics` to draw upon.  Now make a `List<YourInterface>` to hold all instances of things that will draw on your form (stored at Form level).  From the `Paint()` event of your form, iterate over the list and pass the supplied `e.Graphics` to each "thing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a event handler to the paint-event like this:

```
        public static void DrawCircle(Form form)
        {
            form.Paint += OnPaint;
            void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                using (var Pen1 = new Pen(Color.Blue, 9))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pen1, 50, 50, 10, 5);
                }
            }
        }
```

There are a number of downsides:

- There is no possibility to remove circles unless you add some method of un registering the event.
- It will be difficult to manage order of paint-calls, since it will depend on the order the eventhandlers are added.
- It is a bit odd that an external part is drawing on a form. In general, forms and controls should manage their own painting if needed.

You might want to inform the form that it should draw an ellipse, and let the form do the drawing instead.